# How to Concatenate two dataframes(with same names and same columns) from List without loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

```
df_list1=[A,B,C]
df_list2=[A,B,C]
```

I want to use pandas concat to concatenate A(df_list1) to A(df_list2), B to B like wise without loop. Here A, B, C are dataframes. I have tried iterating one of the list and just concatenating one dataframe from each list at a time.

```
i=0
for df in df_list1:
   l=[df,df_list2[i]]
   df=pd.concat(l)
   i=i+1
```

Could someone help me doing this without loop as I have certain time execution requirement(basically I need to reduce time)?

Comment: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Comment: Try iterating through letters not dfs: `df_list3 = [pd.concat(df_list1[x], df_list2[x]) for x in list('ABC')]`

Comment: @Parfait hey but A,B,C are not characters. so I meant writing [A,B,C]. I edited my post

Comment: Then try elementwise loop with `zip`: `df_list3 = [pd.concat(d1, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(df_list1, df_list2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I don't think you can get past using a loop, but</s> you may be interested in the `zip` function, which matches the elements of respective lists as you iterate through them.

```
df_list1=[A,B,C]
df_list2=[A,B,C]
concat_list = []

for x, y in zip(df_list1, df_list2):
    concat_list.append(pd.concat([x, y]))
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, you could use `map`:

```
concat_list = list(map(lambda x: pd.concat([x[0], x[1]), zip(df_list1, df_list2)))
```

Comment: hey thanks @PeptideWitch. If both list are not in order like d1=[B,A,C] and d2=[A,C,B] and still I want to concat A to A and B to B likewise, could you help how can I do it?

Comment: No worries! So your follow-on question can be taken a few different ways. It comes down to how you know that the list is out of order. You could go through each list and check the index of the dataframe or name of a column, or if you already know the order of the lists then you could make an index list: `[1,0,2]` and  `[0,2,1]` then do an iteration: `for x in range(len(l))` and access the dataframe lists using the `x` as your indexer -- `df_list1[index_list.index(x)]`.